# Apache Solr 8.6.1 failed to load a third party plugin

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I am trying to add a Latin stemmer plugin for Solr introduced at [this webpage](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-4229)
I tried to go along with [the documentation](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_6/libs.html#lib-directories) and added following code into `managed-schema`, which is suggesterd at the webpage..

```
  <fieldType name="text_latin" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="org.apache.solr.analysis.LatinNumberConvertFilterFactory" strictMode="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="latin_protwords.txt" />
        <filter class="org.apache.solr.analysis.LatinStemFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

However, I have an error on the local server webpage, which says:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load conf for core [MY INSTANCE]: Can't load schema /[MY WORKSPACE DIRECTORY]/solr-8.6.1/server/solr/[MY INSTANCE]/conf/managed-schema: Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] fieldType "text_latin": Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] analyzer/filter: Error loading class 'org.apache.solr.analysis.LatinNumberConvertFilterFactory'
```

Specifically saying, I created `lib` folder in `solr-8.6.1/server/solr/[MY INSTANCE]/`, and I placed the JAR file that is attached at the website in that folder. Also, I wrote `<lib dir="lib" regex=".*\.jar" />` in `solrconfig.xml`, since the documentation says "All directories are resolved as relative to the Solr core’s `instanceDir`". I also tried `<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/server/solr/[MY INSTANCE]/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />`, but nothing changed.

Also, as the documentation alternatively suggested, I also tried to add the JAR file in `solr-8.6.1/server/solr-webapp/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/`. This created the same error.

Now, I have no idea what else I can do. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: The Solr startup log should show you the jar files that are being loaded. Are you running in cloud or in standalone mode?

Comment: I run Solr in my localhost, which should be standalone mode. I looked at the `solr.log` and I have `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` besides `org.apache.solr.common.SolrException`. This seems that the path does not goes to the JAR file.

Comment: The log shows all the jar files being loaded at the start, so you should be able to see which jar files are being loaded and which are not (and which are being considered).

Comment: The JAR file that I want to use does no seem to be loaded according to the log. Also, `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` occurs when Solr tries to call one of the class files in the JAR file. I want know why it isn't loaded.

Comment: Usually the cause is that the directory doesn't match the expected path. Start by using an absolute path and go from there. Try to drop it together with other files _that do get loaded_ and see if you're able to load it then, then work backwards from there.

Comment: When I went over the log carefully, actually the the plugin seems to be loaded judging from `o.a.s.c.SolrResourceLoader Added 2 libs to classloader, from paths: [/[MY SOLR INSTALL DIRECTORY]/server/solr/[MY INSTANCE]/lib]`. But I could not know from the log whether the JAR file that I wanted to add is specifically loaded. Of course, I still have exceptions that I have got.

Comment: There might be something wrong with JAR file provided on the website that I indicated. Instead, I used [this code](https://github.com/jhu-digital-manuscripts/lucene-latin-stemmer) and generated JAR file by myself, It seems to be working. Thanks for your advice anyway!